# ASP.NET - using javascript to change text of LinkButton on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asplinkbutton

I have a LinkButton that essentially toggles a menu, "show/hide".

So I am doing the show/hide logic in a javascript method called onShowFiltersClick(), that is attached as an OnClientClick event.

But how do I reach (and change) the text value of the button? It is currently being set statically in the .cs file to "Show filters". But I want to toggle this on the client side. And the changes will probably have to persist across postbacks.

But as it stands now, I can't even retrieve the string "Show filters" from the .js, trying everything both sending the button's clientID as a parameter to the javascript and by accessing it through jQuery $ and the button's css class. I then try to view all sorts of parameters, including text, innertext, value and innerHTML.

So how do I access it?

edit: Neha requested a code snippet, so I'm including one of several I have tried:

```
function onShowFiltersClick() {
    var filtersPanel = $('.filters-panel');
    var displayStyle = filtersPanel.css('display');
    filtersPanel.toggle('fast');
    var showFiltersButton = $('.show-filters-button');
    alert(showFiltersButton.text);
    alert(showFiltersButton.innerText);
    alert(showFiltersButton.innerHTML);
    alert(showFiltersButton.value);
    if(displayStyle === 'none')
        $('.price-slider').repaint();
}
```

This produces the following:

function (a){if(f.isFunction(a))return this.each(function(b){var c=f(this);c.text(a.call(this,b,c.text()))});if(typeof a!="object"&&a!==b)return this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||c).createTextNode(a));return f.text(this)}

followed by a bunch of undefined.

Comment: show your code snippet here.. so anyone can check out whats wrong

Comment: Added an example now.

Comment: you can try somethig like: `jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('.mybuttonclass').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).attr('value',Math.floor(0 + Math.random() * (1000 - (0) + 1)));
 });
});`

Comment: HellBaby: You mean just calling it inline? I'm afraid that doesn't change the text of the LinkButton at all. (All I did was comment out the alerts and then paste this line in their stead.)